# Creating a test class for a trigger help!

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I am new to Salesforce and I am struggling to write a simple test class. I haven't written one before though I have been doing a lot of trailhead on it but can't seem to wrap my head around this test class for a trigger.

I have this trigger that Autofills a lookup field called Staff whenever a value is selected from the Appointment_with__c picklist field. It only auto-fills whenever the event is saved:

```
trigger Autofill on Event (before insert, before update) {
    { 
        for (Event e : Trigger.new) 
        {
            
            String [] str = e.Appointment_with__c.split(' ');
            
            
            List<Contact> cont = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName =:str[0] AND LastName =:str[1]];               
            
            
            e.Staff__c = cont[0].Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to create a test class for this?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi and welcome, I recommend you to start by these trails: [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) and [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing). Please review and work on those, if you have more questions let us know and we will help you.

Comment: @AjFmO That's what ive been doing but I am struggling to write an apex test class for this trigger.

Comment: Ok, let's break into pieces, first thing, when do you need to do the changes, before or after records are inserted or updated? - Your contexts are defined 'before insert, before update' but you say ' It only auto-fills whenever the event is saved' which is not because you are setting the value before saving - (not saved). Second, nested loops, which will hit [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), what if you take your query out that for, and loop you String[] -which will look better if List<String>-

Comment: Thanks guys! I would have preferred like an example but I will try my best to follow what you have mentioned. It has to auto populate when it is saved because it takes the value from the picklist and updates the lookup field.